# "Authentication failed" after deployment in a mutualized hosting

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony4

I created a  webapp from the Symfony4 Demo app, including the Login system and multi-language support.
All worked perfectly with the Built-in Apache server in the port 8000.
- When I configured a Xamp apache I needed to generate the '.htaccess' file in the 'public' folder in order to make the website working(composer require symfony/apache-pack), but finally it worked.
- Now I deployed the app in a mutualized hosting server, and configured the .env properly, queries to the DB work, but I'm not able to login to the webapp.

Do you from where can be the problem?
Thx for your help!

> [2019-09-05 11:05:38] request.INFO: Matched route "security_login".
>   {"route":"security_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"security_login","_controller":"App\Controller\SecurityController::login","_locale":"en"},"request_uri":"http://xxx.xxxx.com/en/login","method":"GET"}
>   [] [2019-09-05 11:05:38] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage
>   with an anonymous Token. [] [] [2019-09-05 11:05:39] request.INFO:
>   Matched route "_wdt".
>   {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"984d25"},"request_uri":"http://xxx.xxxx.com/_wdt/984d25","method":"GET"}
>   [] [2019-09-05 11:05:43] request.INFO: Matched route "security_login".
>   {"route":"security_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"security_login","_controller":"App\Controller\SecurityController::login","_locale":"en"},"request_uri":"http://xxx.xxxx.com/en/login","method":"POST"}
>   [] [2019-09-05 11:05:43] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
>   t0.full_name AS full_name_2, t0.username AS username_3, t0.email AS
>   email_4, t0.password AS password_5, t0.roles AS roles_6 FROM xxx_user
>   t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["pierre_admin"] [] [2019-09-05
>   11:05:43] security.INFO: Authentication request failed.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code:
>   0): Bad credentials. at
>   /home/xxxxcom/xxxx.com/xxx_xxxx_com/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:85,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code:
>   0): The presented password is invalid. at
>   /home/xxxxcom/xxxx.com/xxx_xxxx_com/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:58)"}
>   [] [2019-09-05 11:05:43] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure,
>   redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"security_login"} [] [2019-09-05
>   11:05:43] request.INFO: Matched route "security_login".
>   {"route":"security_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"security_login","_controller":"App\Controller\SecurityController::login","_locale":"en"},"request_uri":"http://xxx.xxxx.com/en/login","method":"GET"}
>   [] [2019-09-05 11:05:43] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage
>   with an anonymous Token. [] [] [2019-09-05 11:05:43] request.INFO:
>   Matched route "_wdt".
>   {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"47fb65"},"request_uri":"http://xxx.xxxx.com/_wdt/47fb65","method":"GET"}
>   []

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer ;)
- Php 7.1 not working with Symfony4
- Move to 7.2 works fine